# detect flash and display images instead if not present

Tags: image, flash

what would be a good solution to the following scenario:
a page is supposed to have a few flash buttons in it. we want to check if the user's browser supports
flash (a given version i suppose) and if not - display gifs or jpgs instead.
thanx in advance and have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You can use swfobject library to detect if flash is installed. It will automatically replace your images layer with the flash file. You can get it from google code: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/